# how can I get text of popup in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a input text like below

[image]

when I click inside that, one popup appear

[image]

that has two values like below:

```
<span id="btnSetMaxPrice" style="font-size: 11px" class="tp-co-gr digit tp-cu-po btnSetHighLow btnSetMaxPrice">70,465</span>
```

and when click on one of them then

in the input text, it writes that number

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read its textContent property.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('btnSetMaxPrice').textContent)
```

```html
<span id="btnSetMaxPrice" style="font-size: 11px" class="tp-co-gr digit tp-cu-po btnSetHighLow btnSetMaxPrice">70,465</span>
```